# Badges with zero count no longer returning zero

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

For queries such as `http://api.{sitename}.com/1.0/users/{id}` if a badge count is zero, the API is no longer returning `"gold": 0`, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed now.